# NodeJS stream with multiple 'data' event handler and race condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, request, koa

I'd like to consume a NodeJS request stream multiple (two) times in two separated Koa middlewares, so I added listeners to its 'data' event. It works now, however I fear there is a race condition behind it, because- based on the documentation- after adding the first event handler the stream starts calling it as soon as there is any data available. Can it happen that the second event listener doesn't receive all of the chunks if there are other codes between the subscriptions? Or is it somehow avoided (how?)?

Thank you!

Comment: You can `.pause()` a stream (won't emit `data` events), attach your event listeners, and then `.resume()` it. While paused, the data will accumulate in an internal buffer til you resume it. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause and https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume

Answer (score 1):

Node.js streams use [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to send events.  Anyone listening on an event (it doesn't matter how many listeners there are) will receive the event.  So each of your subscribers will get the data event.

The documentation is there to warn you that by listening to the 'data' event, it puts the stream into 'legacy' mode (or streams v1). It means that if for some reason, one of your subscribers misses a message, it's gone forever.

However, Node.js also supports stream piping.  You can pipe one readable stream to multiple output streams, and the data will be sent to each of those readers (with a separate read buffer for each of them).  At the same time, if the readable stream ends, it will end both of the writable streams.  Each stream will have its own read buffer, meaning that they won't miss any messages if they stop listening to the stream temporarily (for some strange reason).

```
streamA.pipe(streamB)
streamA.pipe(streamC)
```

Comment: I just wanted to take a moment to thank you for your short and succinct answer.  I have been studying and trying to wrap my mind around node stream and the pipe methods and your answer went a long way toward clarifying these concepts in my mind.